# std::function with lambda error for SDL event callbacks

Tags: c++, lambda, sdl, eventhandler, std-function

I simply want to pass a lambda function to a function for callbacks. I am using `std::function` for callbacks. I need to pass data to this function and this is where I am running into problems. The code below errors saying "cannot convert to the expected type". The goal is to use callbacks for events with `SDL`. I am not sure if this is even the right way to go about doing this. I am storing the callback function in a `unordered_map` with the key being an `SDL_Event.type` and a `vector` of `std::function`.

I call the `dispatch()` in the event polling and `subscribe` in the setup. The error occurs in the `[]` of the `subscribe()` lambda

```
// main.cpp
window->subscribe(SDL_KEYDOWN, [](SDL_Event& ev) -> void {
    std::cout << "key pressed" << std::endl;
});

// eventhandler.cpp
void EventHandler::subscribe(int _event, std::function<void(const SDL_Event&)> _callback)
{
    m_callbacks[_event].push_back(_callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very stupid mistake made... The parameters did not match. The correct code that works is below. I.e. I did not have the `const` in the lambda...

```
window->subscribe(SDL_KEYDOWN, [](const SDL_Event& ev) -> void {
    std::cout << "key pressed" << std::endl;
});

void EventHandler::subscribe(int _event, std::function<void(const SDL_Event&)> _callback)
{
    m_callbacks[_event].push_back(_callback);
}
```